# How to properly check internet connection on android device?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to check internet connection on an Android device and I tried some methods but all of these have a problem : if I turn on mobile connection but I haven't internet in my phone offer Android detects that the internet connection is available.

I tried with `InetAddress` pinging Google but it doesn't work, never times out.

---

I even tried with `HttpUrlConnection` that also connects to Google but never times out, only with mobile data connection. Seems that it never reaches end.

*Code with `HttpUrlConnection`*

```
//It is in a boolean method that return true if Internet is available
try {
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL("https://www.google.com").openConnection());
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Test");
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
    urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(3500);
    urlConnection.connect();
    return urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200;
} catch (SocketTimeoutException socketTimeoutException) {
    Log.e("Internet Connection", "Internet Connection error : " + socketTimeoutException);

    return false;
} catch (IOException exception) {
    Log.e("Internet Connection", "Internet Connection error : " + exception);

    return false;
}
```

---

The last try I did is with `SocketAddress` but it always returns true with the mobile connection.

*Code with `SocketAddress`*

```
//Even in the same method
try {
    int timeout = 3500;
    Socket socket = new Socket();
    SocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress("8.8.8.8", 53);

    socket.connect(socketAddress, timeout);
    socket.close();
} catch (IOException exception) {
        return false;
}
return true;
```

What I should do? I tried also with `getActiveNetworkInfo()` but I read that it checks only if network is available even if there isn't internet connection.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Define "Check internet connection".  Do you want to check that you're on a network?  That the network can access the outside in general?  That the network can access some specific computer?  And in your secodn example-  what is 8.8.8.8?  Hitting a random port on a random machine is unlikely to do what you want.

Comment: Basically I want to check connection before using firebase. My app has a splash screen and before starts to download data I want to check if app has Internet access to communicate with Firebase. 8.8.8.8 is dns of google, so it tries to connect to google server, isn't a right way?

Comment: Doesn't it throw a connection timed out exception In your SocketAddress method when there is no connection? It should. If it doesn't there is a connection. Your socket method looks ok.

Comment: Yes, it throws, but only with wifi. If I turn on mobile connection and i have no internet socket method doesn't return or throw anything

Answer (score 0):

There is a library for that, 
Try this

```
implementation 'com.treebo:internetavailabilitychecker:1.0.2'
```

[Documentation](https://github.com/AggarwalAnkit/InternetAvailabilityChecker)

Comment: I will try it as soon as I can!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code for checking the internet connection.

```
public class CheckInternetConnection {

    private Context context;
    public CheckInternetConnection(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    //checking internet connection if internet is connected then it will return true
    // otherwise it will return false
    public boolean netCheck(){
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo nInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        boolean isConnected = nInfo != null && nInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
        return isConnected;
    }

}
```

For real-time network monitoring you can use the following library [Merlin](https://github.com/novoda/merlin) and [Tovuti](https://github.com/AndroidStudyOpenSource/tovuti). I have already use tovuti and it works nicely.

Comment: If you read my question, it say that I already tried with this, and I think that it checks only for network, like if Wifi is connected to a network, even if the internet connection is unavailable

Comment: Doesn't `getActiveNetworkInfo()` only check if **network** is available and return true even if the device isn't internet connected?

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in checking internet connection before accessing firebase. Even if your check goes through, the connection can be lost a second later, when you try to access firebase.
Better, just try to access firebase and handle any errors correctly.

Comment: Ok, but I want to check internet connection in background in all application. This solution works perfectly in splash screen but in the entirely app how can i do?